Function that returns a pointer to a Fortran Class is called getting called twice
The following code used to work fine under gfortan 11 but is causing the weirdest behavior in later versions.
A patern I use for constructing classes is to defined a constructor function with returns a class pointer. Then to make subclass variants, I call those constructors from a factory function. The smallest example case.
module test

implicit none

type :: foo
end type

contains

function make()
implicit none

class (foo), pointer :: make

make => foo_construct()

end function

function foo_construct()
implicit none

class (foo), pointer :: foo_construct

allocate(foo_construct)
write (*,*) 'construct_foo'

end function

end module

A driver program for this is
program test_construct
use test
implicit none

class (foo), pointer :: foo_instant

foo_instant => make()
deallocate(foo_instant)

end program

When I run this I get the output
% ./test_prog              
 construct_foo
 construct_foo

Program received signal SIGBUS: Access to an undefined portion of a memory object.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x102b5eccf
#1  0x102b5dd23
#2  0x18cd7a583
#3  0x102523cff
#4  0x102523d57
zsh: bus error  ./test_prog

Why is my foo_construct function getting called twice?
Update
The output of gfortran --version is
% gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 14.2.0
Copyright (C) 2024 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This is also running on an Apple M1

I’ve used gfortran, NAG and intel compilers and none of them replicate your problem. They just call foo_construct once and terminate normally.

Looks like a bug in gfortran, and should be reported to the developers.  To workaround the issue, you can use a RESULT variable, i.e., function make() result(res).

I can't reproduced this with gfortran 12.2.0 on WSL. Please provide the output of gfortran --version for a case that fails for you.

Switching it to use a result variable fixed the issue. I'll open a bug with report.

@IanBush, it's a bug.  I can reproduce the issue with x86_64-*-freebsd with 13.2 and top-of-tree gfortran.

FWIW, here is a test page for OP's original code  https://godbolt.org/z/s9c94sMff (which works for gfortran <= 12.4 and fails for >= 13.1) and for the modified version with result variables https://godbolt.org/z/d17o6KW3T (which works for all versions)
